# Using Btree to store data of dictionary?

Tags: b-tree

I have a problem using btree to store data of 100.000 words in a dictionary ( a word include a head and definition), i don't know how to hash 100.000 words to 100.000 different key with a hash function , my teacher give some hint that just hash 3 first character of word but i can't image what would do with some word have more than 3 character. please help me T_T

Comment: Here's another hint: Using the Ascii values of letters of the alphabet, come up with a hashing formula that maintains the alphabetization of the words in the dictionary, just using the first 3 letters of each word.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is probably that hash-collisions are fine: you calculate a hash (for example by adding the ASCCI values of the first three characters; but that hardly qualifies as "hash" in the real world) and compare the hashes. If they are equal, you do a (more expensive) string comparison. Like:

```
int compare(Node *left, Node *right) {
    if (left->hash == right->hash) {
        return stringCompare(left, right);
    }

    if (left->hash < right->hash) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Gilbert Le Blanc and DarkDust for your help. But it still can't help me get out of circle.I have a lot of question . When adding a lot of word (more than 100.000) Btree need re-balance many time, and it will take long time, how can i fix it ?   What can i do with 2 word have the same first 3 letters  ?